# Why reCaptcha don't work on my wordpress comments template

Tags: php, wordpress, recaptcha

I'm trying to avoid spam in the comments of my first wordpress theme, and the question is that I've followed all the [Google PHP API instructions](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php), and it's showing perfectly, but the validating is going wrong, I think cause I can post comments entering wrong words in the recaptcha.

Exploiting the issue, I would also like to know how I can put the error message returned, together with the submit button.

This is the comments.php form fragment:

```
<form class="comments-form" action="verify.php" method="post" id="commentform">

           ...

    <?php
      require_once('recaptchalib.php');
      $publickey = "my_pulic_key";
      echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey, $error);
    ?>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" tabindex="5" value="Enviar" />
        <label for="submit"><?php echo $error ?></label>
        <input type="hidden" name="comment_post_ID" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
    </p>

    <?php do_action('comment_form', $post->ID); ?> 

</form>
```

And this is the verify.php code:

```
    <?php
      require_once('recaptchalib.php');
      $privatekey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; //clave privada
      $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                    $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                    $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                    $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

  if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
    $error = $resp->error;
  } else {
    // Your code here to handle a successful verification
    echo "¡Recaptcha correcto!";
    //do_action("wp-comment-post.php");??????I DON´T KNOW IF THIS IS OK.
  }
  ?>
```

EDIT: I've tried with the form action "verify.php" but only redirect me to an empty page.
Which is the correct action that I should use?

Comment: Please, show only the code, relevant to your question. No need to put the whole form here.

Comment: Thanks, now there's only the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error:

```
$response = recaptcha_check_answer (...);//<- ?!!

if (!$resp->is_valid) {
```

At first the variable is called `$response`, then `$resp`.

Comment: Thanks, i've change this error, but this don't solve my problem.

Comment: @evega Why did you change form action to "wp-comments-post.php"? Now your correct verify.php is not activated. Switch it back to verify or add verification code to wp-comments-post.php.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm crazy after many changes. So I deduce that the correct form action is verify.php? But with this action, when I submit a comment, always was redirected to a blank page with de URL: "http://www.myweb.com/verify.php"

Comment: Then, in the succesfull verification action I should do the "wp-comments-post.php" action?

Comment: @evega It's quite hard, cause you 'll have to call functions from  wp-commentss-post from within verify.php